# Something is not working, my react native app is not working

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, api, mobile

I got code from this website: https://www.google.com/amp/s/aboutreact.com/react-native-login-and-signup/amp/
Please help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mDMZw.png)

Answer (score 0):

Either code you write or dependencies libraries use React native Reanimated 2 worklet.

In your project structures, Look at a file named `babel.config.js` and add the code below:

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module: metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin'
  ]
};
```

Comment: still not work now show :Screen/LoginScreen.js: Cannot find module ' metro-react-native-babel-preset'
Require stack:
- /Users/user/secsocial/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/plugins.js
- /Users/user/secsocial/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/config/files/index.js
- /Users/user/secsocial/node_modules/@babel/core/lib/index.js
- /Users/user/secsocial/node_modules/metro-transform-worker/src/index.js
- /Users/user/secsocial/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/Worker.js
- /Users/user/secsocial/node_modules/jest-worker/build/workers/processChild.js

Comment: Do you use React Native CLI or Expo?

Comment: I use react native cli

Comment: what you think about it?

Comment: In case you're new with React Native Ecosystem, Try to work with starter pack with all fundamental dependencies configured out of the box. https://www.reactnativeschool.com/simple-free-expo-starter-template-with-navigation-and-testing

Comment: yes I am new and totally green when it comes to react native thanks for the link I will see the site :)

Comment: what is the version of react native and react in your project?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this method first:

**npx**

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

**Yarn**

```
yarn start --reset-cache
```

I hope this method can solve your problem